# I want textbox column should be DateTime column in a datagridview in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview, cell-formatting

i am writing the following code in cell formatting event of datagridview in c#

```
this.dgvfrm.Columns["expdt"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
```

after writing this when i enter dd/MM/yyyy format in datagridview textbox column it shows an error. I show you the image

[image]

i don't understand what i want to do know?

Comment: handle the event _DataError_ and just put nothing in it. This should be a start. It could pop that error because you are trying to format a data that couldn't match the format. That is not a valid DateTime.

Comment: if i use data error event focus is not going to other control....,

Comment: try to check the data you put in this column. If they comme from a database run your query to see the result.

Comment: problem is when i am inserting "dd/MM/yyyy" like this i am getting that error

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because the value in the data grid cell, at least one of them, isn't a valid date and time and can't be formatted that way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed something like this :

```
private void dgvfrm_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.ColumnIndex != yourFormattigColumnIndex || e.Value == null)  //Added the null check
        return;

    dgvfrm.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = ((DateTime)e.Value).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

I think this should work (might have some typo/syntax but the idea is there)

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.